# Can @Qualifier "see" through a chain of dependencies?

Tags: java, spring

I have some beans declared in a config file:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate()
{
    return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory());
}

@Bean
public ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory()
{
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient());
    //some config...
    return factory;
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("key1")
public HttpClient httpClient()
{
    //some config here too..
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("key2")
public HttpClient httpClient()
{
    //some config here too..
}
```

Then I want to autowire RestTemplate twice:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("key1")
RestTemplate restTemplate1;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("key2")
RestTemplate restTemplate2;
```

1. Would this work?
2. Since I have a chain of dependencies, can @Qualifier see through this chain up until `HttpClinet` needs to be injected?
3. Should I make `RestTemplate` @Scope "prototype"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't work because you use @Qualifier on HttpClient in configuration class instead on RestTemplate.

You would need something like this (I'm writing this out of head, so it may not work 100%):

```
@Bean(name="key1")
public RestTemplate restTemplate1()
{
    return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory1());
}

@Bean(name="key2")
public RestTemplate restTemplate2()
{
    return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory2());
}

@Bean
public ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory1()
{
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient1());
    //some config...
    return factory;
}


@Bean
public ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory2()
{
    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient2());
    //some config...
    return factory;
}

public HttpClient httpClient1()
{
    //some config here too..
}

public HttpClient httpClient2()
{
    //some config here too..
}
```

**EDIT:**

It's possible to avoid code duplication, but it depends on your specific configuration and if you really need HttpClient and ClientHttpRequestFactory as beans when you are using RestTemplate.

For example:

```
    @Bean(name = "key1")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate1() {
        return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient(/* params */)));
    }

    @Bean(name = "key2")
    public RestTemplate restTemplate2() {
        return new RestTemplate(clientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient(/* params */)));
    }

    public ClientHttpRequestFactory clientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClient httpClient) {
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
        return factory;
    }

    public HttpClient httpClient(/* paramn */) {
        /* create HttpClient using params  */
    }
```

Comment: So I still have to duplicate all dependent beans. I think I get it: So @Qualifier doesn't spare me of duplicating beans; it instead **allows** me to do this since in Spring I cannot have 2 beans o same type (thing that I just found out). Right?

Comment: @Daniel It's possible if you don't mark ClientHttpRequestFactory and HttpClient as beans, see edited answer.